# Buildozer android APK Import Error

Tags: android, python-2.7, apk, kivy, buildozer

Please help.

My kivy program runs perfect on the desktop (Mac OS, using buildozer and Android-new toolchain).

However once i build the APK and test it on the android Emulator (Andyroid) i get the following error in the logcat regarding the user class that i import. Do i need to specify it somewhere in the spec file or something ?

```
D/HostConnection( 1738): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7f2d2b0, tid 1865
I/python  ( 1738): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 2.0>
I/python  ( 1738): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Imagination Technologies>
I/python  ( 1738): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <PowerVR SGX 544MP>
I/python  ( 1738): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
I/python  ( 1738): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
I/python  ( 1738): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
I/python  ( 1738): [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
I/python  ( 1738): [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
D/AndroidRuntime( 2115): 
D/AndroidRuntime( 2115): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 2115): CheckJNI is OFF
D/dalvikvm( 2115): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 2115): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 2115): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 2115): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/AndroidRuntime( 2115): Calling main entry com.android.commands.settings.SettingsCmd
D/dalvikvm( 2115): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 157 unimplemented (abstract) methods
D/AndroidRuntime( 2115): Shutting down VM
D/SettingsProvider( 2213): User 0 external modification to /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db; event=8
D/SettingsProvider( 2213): User 0 updating our caches for /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
I/python  ( 1738):  Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  ( 1738):    File "main.py", line 72, in <module>
I/python  ( 1738):      from user import User
I/python  ( 1738):  ImportError: cannot import name User
I/python  ( 1738): Python for android ended.
I/HostConnection( 1738): ~HostConnection
V/SDL     ( 1738): onPause()
E/dalvikvm( 1738): Loading ARM symbol: Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativePause
E/dalvikvm( 1738): Loading ARM symbol: Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativePause__
E/dalvikvm( 1738): Loading ARM symbol: Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativePause
E/dalvikvm( 1738): Loading ARM symbol: Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativePause__
E/dalvikvm( 1738): Loading ARM symbol: Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativePause
E/dalvikvm( 1738): Loading ARM symbol: Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativePause__
E/dalvikvm( 1738): Loading ARM symbol: Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativePause
E/dalvikvm( 1738): Loading ARM symbol: Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativePause__
E/dalvikvm( 1738): Loading ARM symbol: Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativePause
E/dalvikvm( 1738): Loading ARM symbol: Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativePause__
E/dalvikvm( 1738): Loading ARM symbol: Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativePause
E/dalvikvm( 1738): Loading ARM symbol: Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativePause__
E/dalvikvm( 1738): Loading ARM symbol: Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativePause
E/dalvikvm( 1738): Loading ARM symbol: Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativePause__
E/dalvikvm( 1738): Loading ARM symbol: Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativePause
V/SDL     ( 1738): nativePause()
F/libc    ( 1738): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 1738 (rg.test.rides16)
I/DEBUG   ( 1315): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
```

Snippet from main.py

```
from user import User
from category import Category
from advert import Advert
from attending import Attending
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `user` package in python 2.7, and it overrides your own `user` package. Try changing the name to something else, like `user_`. It's a minor bug in the buildozer.